# Sending an official transcript for a M.Sc program that I will not be able to complete to a PhD program in the US

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have been admitted recently to a Ph.D. program in the US. I am currently completing a Masters degree. I am required to submit an official transcript for my Masters and my Bachelor's degree. The problem is that I can not find a suitable advisor for my Masters thesis. I did have a thesis advisor but I left him some months ago for several reasons. I am considering the possibility of not continuing with my Masters given that I have been admitted to a Ph.D. program (this is not my fault; I really can not find anyone who is actively working in my field at my university). I registered for Masters thesis course for Fall 2019 and then, for various reasons, I left my advisor. I am worried however about the fact that I will be submitting a Masters transcript that does not show any Masters thesis work. I have to register a thesis course for Spring 2020 but I can not because I do not have any advisor. The official transcript that I will be sending to the PhD program contains courses up to Spring 2019 (the Fall 2019 Masters thesis course does not have any grade next to it).

Will  this affect my admissions to the PhD program? The offer of admissions is not conditional upon me completing my Masters. However, I am worried that it might affect my admission.

Comment: If you've been admitted already then I doubt that you have any problem. Just have the university send it. Caveat: I don't get to make the decision, but expect the decisions, having been made, are final.

Comment: Was the acceptance based on having finished the degree?

Comment: I received an admissions offer. No. It was not based on having to finish the Masters degree. However, I am still waiting the final decision which, I think, will be made after they review my official transcript. I used unofficial transcripts in my application.

Comment: In your PhD application did you indicate you expect to get the master's degree?

Comment: Yes. I think so. All application forms have this question.

Comment: Based on the comments it is no longer so clear that you are safe. But it is what it is. Have it sent and hope for the best.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please clarify? The admissions offer did not say that I have to finish my Masters.